# How to create a religion in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Just got the Gods and Kings expansion and was playing 3 player game with friends. They both made a religion and I was over 1000 in faith and still could not work out how to create a religion or get a Great Prophet.

How do you create a religion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two steps:

First, when your Faith reaches a certain level you can found a Pantheon.  However, every time someone founds a Pantheon, the threshold to found the next one goes up.

Next, when your Faith reaches another threshold you'll get a Great Prophet - from what I can tell this will only happen if you've got a Pantheon, though.  You can then use the Great Prophet to create your full religion.

There's one wrinkle, too: only a certain number of religions can exist so if they've all been founded already (by your friends or CPUs) you won't be able to found one.

From [this guide](http://www.carlsguides.com/strategy/civilization5/religion/):

> There is a max to the number of religions that can be founded in a game, based on Map size. About 2/3 of Civs can found a religion in any game if you do not add more players to a custom game.
>
> - Huge maps offer 12 players 7 religions
> - Large 10 players with 6 Religions
> - Standard 8 Players with 5 Religions
> - Small 6 Players with 4 Religions
> - Tiny 4 Players with 3 Religions
> - Duel 2 Players with 2 Religions

Comment: Well there was no AI, just me and two friends. I had plenty of faith. I still don't get how I was suppose to get a Great prophet.

Comment: It sounds to me like your friends beat you to the first two Pantheon slots and you didn't get one.  The number of religion slots is always less than the number of players in the game, so all 3 of you couldn't have a religion.  And you'll only get a Great Prophet once you do have a Pantheon, so you were just out of luck.

Comment: @lilserf Re: And you'll only get a Great Prophet once you do have a Pantheon, so you were just out of luck.
Interesting exception I experienced: You don't seem to be able to get one through faith, but I have successfully gotten a GP by building the Hagia Sofia when all the pantheon slots were taken, and was jump-started to a religion. It let me pick a pantheon belief as part of founding the religion even though all slots were full. Not sure if its supposed to be possible or not, but it did work.

Comment: That's a really interesting wrinkle!

Comment: Additional restriction, at some point a founded religion may be Enhanced by a second great prophet. At this time no new pantheons may be founded.
I can't find the exact number, but it seems the cap to total number of religions is around 2/3rds the total number of starting civilizations